# MariaDB 10.3 - Boolean seach returns different results for Innodb and MyISAM

Tags: mysql, mariadb, full-text-search, innodb

I've tried to disable InnoDB stopwords, but it's still not working with **`the`**, **`this`**, etc. keywords when included, also min_word is set to 2.

I've read somewhere on stackoverflow that someone mentioned that MyISAM is ignoring fulltext index and returning results, while InnoDB will not ignore and fail to deliver results.

Is there any way to fix this for InnoDB?

Here's the example..

`The flower is red and beautiful.`

InnoDB

```
SELECT name FROM x MATCH (x.name) AGAINST ('+the* +flower*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
Showing rows 0
```

MyISAM

```
SELECT name FROM x MATCH (x.name) AGAINST ('+the* +flower*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
Showing rows 1
```

**EDIT 1:**

Here are the settings: (stopwords are disabled and set to empty table)

```
aria_force_start_after_recovery_failures    0
ft_boolean_syntax   + -><()~*:""&|
ft_max_word_len     84
ft_min_word_len     2
ft_query_expansion_limit    20
ft_stopword_file    
innodb_ft_aux_table     
innodb_ft_cache_size    8000000
innodb_ft_enable_diag_print     OFF
innodb_ft_enable_stopword   ON
innodb_ft_max_token_size    84
innodb_ft_min_token_size    2
innodb_ft_num_word_optimize     2000
innodb_ft_result_cache_limit    2000000000
innodb_ft_server_stopword_table     local/my_stopwords
innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree   2
innodb_ft_total_cache_size  640000000
innodb_ft_user_stopword_table   local/my_stopwords
```

**EDIT 2:**

Fixed by changing `my.cnf` to

```
innodb_ft_enable_stopword = 0
```

Suggested by **@Raymond Nijland**

Comment: MyISAM and InnoDB use different default stopwords and min of max settings..   `the` is a stopword for full text indexing..

Comment: MySQL manual [Full-Text Stopwords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) and [Fine-Tuning MySQL Full-Text Search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html) which explains the min and max words size settings between MyISAM and InnoDB..

Comment: ... if you still can't figure it out .. See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I've read those and edited the post with my settings of innodb and myisam for `ft_` values

Comment: *"(stopwords are disabled and set to empty table)"*  You sure that it is disabled i clearly see -> `innodb_ft_enable_stopword   ON` between the line in the settings ..

Comment: The manual said to disable on innodb you have to enable it and set it to empty table for example table/my_stopwords

Comment: try `innodb_ft_enable_stopword OFF` Also consider reasking/moving this question to https://dba.stackexchange.com/ instead as this is a MySQL database configuration question which is general considerd to be [offtopic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here..

Comment: Will post it there, thanks for the input and will post results here from change to OFF

Comment: Yeah, you are indeed right. innodb_ft_enable_stopword OFF instead of adding custom table solved issue for InnoDB.